# Using nx console in Visual Studio Code gives error invalid configuration file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, nrwl-nx

Using nx console in Visual Studio Code gives an error:

```
> Executing task: ng generate @ngrx/schematics:feature --name=TestIt --no-flat --no-interactive --dry-run <

> An invalid configuration file was found ['C:\views\git\fipo_fe\angular.json']. Please delete the file before running the command. <
```

Copying the command and use it (inside Visual Code) in a Terminal, it works fine.

```
C:\views\git\fipo_fe>ng generate @ngrx/schematics:feature --name=TestIt --no-flat --no-interactive --dry-run
Your global Angular CLI version (9.0.5) is greater than your local
version (9.0.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
CREATE apps/fipo/src/app/test-it/test-it.actions.ts (260 bytes)
CREATE apps/fipo/src/app/test-it/test-it.reducer.spec.ts (331 bytes)
CREATE apps/fipo/src/app/test-it/test-it.reducer.ts (390 bytes)
CREATE apps/fipo/src/app/test-it/test-it.effects.spec.ts (597 bytes)
CREATE apps/fipo/src/app/test-it/test-it.effects.ts (581 bytes)
CREATE apps/fipo/src/app/test-it/test-it.selectors.spec.ts (322 bytes)
CREATE apps/fipo/src/app/test-it/test-it.selectors.ts (226 bytes)

NOTE: The "dryRun" flag means no changes were made.
```

If i delete angular.json, i will get the message

```
The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

In the console and in the terminal.

I deleted Visual Studio Code and reinstalled it, and also the nx console plugin.

Can somone help me here?

Version Information:

nx console

```
Name: Nx Console
Id: nrwl.angular-console
Description: Nx Console for Visual Studio Code. The user interface app for the Angular CLI
Version: 11.1.3
Publisher: nrwl
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nrwl.angular-console
```

Visual Studio Code

```
Version: 1.43.0 (user setup)
Commit: 78a4c91400152c0f27ba4d363eb56d2835f9903a
Date: 2020-03-09T19:47:57.235Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

Comment: Do you have an @nrwl/workspace? Means: Did you run either the `npx create-nx-workspace ...` command or run `ng add @nrwl/workspace` with successful executed schematics? You can verify if you have the apps/libs directories and a **nx.json** file, that contains all the projects in your angular.json or workspace.json file.

Comment: Yes, we use the nx world with 7 libraries/projects inside. But i have also other projects with only angular inside, they have the same problem. It gives an error on the angular.json file of that project.

Comment: I had the old angular console on the system. It gaves the same error. So i uninstalled it, also visual studio code, deleted .vscode in user directorey and installed vscode with nx plugin again.Still the same. :-(

Comment: It looks like the plugin uses the wrong version of ng. But wich one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I had a defined default directory in powershell profile, in which was an old version of angular-cli in node_modules. Removed the powershell profile and everything works fine.

Looks like nx console starts to seach for ng command in default directory of powershell.